# Date conversion with day time saving

Tags: database, oracle

I have some old data from oracle and the time is in milliseconds generated from Java.

I use this conversion:

```
to_date('19700101000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')+ column/86400
```

And it always have a 5 hour shift to the actual time (which I cannot figure out why), so I just directly subtract 5/24 from the date above.

But it does not comes with day time conversion so in winter it is correct but for summer time it is 1 hour shift. How can I solve this?

Also if any one can point why there is a 5 hour shift will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5 hour shift is probably caused by the difference between your local time (Central Time Zone, based on your user name ) and UTC time. Actually the shift should be 6 hours (CST is UTC - 6), so you've probably got it backwards; your summer time is probably closer to correct, and your winter time is still off by an hour.

Comment: Oh right. That millis is GMT. Here is -5 Eastern Time so in winter is correct and in summer we have day light saving so shifted an hour. :)

Comment: OK. Thought from your username you were in Texas, which is Central Time. :-)